Yarn cannot find nodejs especially in VS Code
When I run yarn with PowerShell in VS Code. I got message like this:
yarn

yarn install v1.22.22
$ node preinstall.js
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.

But if I run with Windows PowerShell (not in VS Code's internal Windows Powershell), it works. If I run with other terminal in VS Code, like git bash, it works too, which may indicate that my environments/path variables are with little problem. It is also ok in my webstorm.
Problem in vscode
Same command in windows terminal is OK
Versions:

VS Code: April 2024 (version 1.89)
Node: 20.12.2
Yarn: 1.22.22

I have already run set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned, however, problem still exists. I also reinstalled Node.js and Yarn.

I finally solved by completely reinstalling vscode following How to completely uninstall vscode.
I thought it might be vscode's bug but I still don't know why. When I called $Env:Path on my vscode's integrated terminal and windows terminal, I got different resultsn. The results got in vscode's WT are much more chaotic (it may contain my old paths) than WT, which might be the reason. They finally became same when I reinstalled my vscode.
